# Magento 1.7 - Cannot initialize the indexer process for Product Prices

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

After a recent migration from Magento Professional to Magento Community (ver. 1.7.0.2), I am unable to initiate the Magento indexer on the "Product Prices" index.  I receive the following error:

"Cannot initialize the indexer process."

After inspecting var/log/exception.log, I see the following stack trace whenever I try to index:

```
2013-05-09T20:50:42+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Trace: #0 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCard/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(187): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Default.php(120): Enterprise_GiftCard_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(385): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default->reindexAll()
#8 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(209): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(178): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->massReindexAction()
#13 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massReindex')
#14 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#15 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#16 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#17 /www/sites/<my site>/files/html/shop/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#18 {main}
```

This is obviously a table issue, but is there any way to figure out specifically what might be missing?

The indexer works for all other indexes. This is the only one experiencing difficulty, and in the Magento Admin, it reads "REINDEX REQUIRED."

EDIT: I have tried to use the Magento DB Repair utility, with the source DB being a fresh Magento Community db. Every time I do, it says no changes need to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by disabling all my 3rd party extensions, except for the ones marked Mage_*

Comment: Were you able to enable the 3rd party extensions again?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I never isolated which extension was causing the problem, but the extension causing the issue wasn't being used, so I ignored it.